# String from xml which is an anchor tag not showing list of browser when clicking it

Tags: android, android-webview, android-xml

I have a **paragraph** in the `xml` file. in that **paragraph** I have some string as a link like below:

```
which can be located at `<a href="https://www/tutorial.html">https://www.tutorial.com </a>.` this is
```

When clicking on it, it should launch the URL in the browser.

Is the implementation correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it.

You need to call `setMovementMethod`:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

2nd

```
textView.setLinksClickable(true);
```

in XML should be

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"
/>
```

Make sure you set your text using `Html.fromHtml` in this way it will read the html anchor tags as anchor and clicking on it will open the browser.

you can also create a `WebView` and pass the String of the `link` as a `URL` to open it in your `Application` not using external browser.
I hope it helps.

Comment: This part is most important ---- "Make sure you set your text using Html.fromHtml in this way it will read the html anchor tags as anchor and clicking on it will open the browser."

Comment: <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:linksClickable="true"
/> This got worked for me... thanks Sahil...

Answer (score 0):

You are using an html tag in String if you want to href tag to be clicked you need to load this string into a webView and then you it'll be clickable and function exactly what you want.
But if you want to show in a TextView then just put your url in the String like https://www/tutorial.html.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your string.xml file

```
<string name="link">&lt;a href="http://www.google.com">Google&lt;/a></string>

((TextView) findViewById(R.id.link)).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.link)).setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.link)));
```